# set-up startup class in glassfish server

Tags: java, migration, ejb, glassfish-3, startup

I have a **ejb** application which is currently deploy on **weblogic** server now i want to deploy it on **glassfish server 3.1**, so my question is can any buddy tell me how to set up start-up class on **glassfish** server.

Comment: Have you tried `@Startup` class with `@PostConstruct` method

Comment: if you have worked on weblogic server, so you know you can set up start up class through administration tool, i want the same in glassfish

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener to get notified about the lifecycle events of the server by implementing `com.sun.appserv.server.LifecycleListener`.

```
public class StartupListener implements LifecycleListener {

   public void handleEvent(LifecycleEvent event) throws ServerLifecycleException {

            if (LifecycleEvent.STARTUP_EVENT == event.getEventType()) {

            }       
     }
}
```

Now configuring listener in domain.xml

```
<application name="APPLICATION_NAME" object-type="user">
<property name="isLifecycle" value="true" />
<property name="class-name" value="com.startup.StartupListener" />
</application>
```

I am not very familiar with glassfish, but it can also be done through admin console. You can get further information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beamc/index.html).

Comment: i can't find com.sun.appserv.server.LifecycleListener interface, in my glassfish i have appserv-rt.jar but no such interface is there

Comment: @pd27 Not sure about jar, try glassfish-api.jar else appserv-deployment.jar/appserv-ext.jar